# Why do I always have to Double Tap a UITab Bar item?

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to make use of a Tab Bar for the first time. So I dragged a Tab Bar Controller from the object library onto the storyBoard. Something basic with no code at all and then I built. My issue is on the simulator I always have to **double tap** on a specific tab bar item to move to the view controller. Also I noticed this scenario

If I Single tap on tabBar item A and then go onto tap tabBar item C. I'm taken back to A. So I can only select A by double tapping on tabBar item A. No single taps...

Whats going on  and what is the solution to this issue?

I don't think thats normal because I've seen videos on this, it always a single tap.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: So if you make a new project in Xcode and select "Tabbed app" you need to double tap to move between the two view controllers?

Comment: Yes I still need to double tap..

Comment: check the viewDidLoad Function in the view controller that need doble tap something is making to hold the load

Comment: Then something is wrong with your simulator settings. Try Hardware->Erase all content and settings.  Try a different simulator

Comment: Tried that just now. Still the same issue.

Comment: I also noticed that its really not all out double tapping. To select the tab bar item I tap once then wait for what seems like about a second or less , then I tap again before that tab item is selected. Double tapping really fast doesn't even work..

Comment: Do you think reinstalling the simulator will fix this ?